# Accessing nested relationship with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having  trouble figuring out how to access a nested relationship within Laravel. The specific example I have is a Movie that has many entires in my Cast table which has one entry in my People table. These are my models:

**MOVIE**

```
class Movie extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'movie_id';
    protected $table = 'movie';

    // Relationships
    public function cast()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('MovieCast', 'movie_id');
    }
}
```

**MOVIECAST**

```
class MovieCast extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'movie_cast';

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person', 'person_id');
    }

    public function netflix()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Movie', 'movie_id');
    }
}
```

**PERSON**

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';
    protected $table = 'people';

    public function movieCast()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MovieCast', 'person_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller I can access the cast (containing `person_id` and `role_id`) like so:

```
public function movie($id)
    {
        $movie = Movie::find($id);
        $cast = $movie->cast();

        return View::make('movie')->with(array(
            'movie' => $movie,
            'cast' => $cast
        ));
    }
```

...but I don't know how to access the corresponding `name` field in my `People` table.

**EDIT 1:**

Using the classes exactly as defined below in @msturdy's answer, with the controller method above I try to render the `person` names like so inside my view:

```
@foreach($cast->person as $cast_member)
        {{$cast_member->person->name}}
    @endforeach
```

Doing this i get the error:

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$person`

[image]

I don't know if it makes a difference or not but I have no `id` field on my `People` table. `person_id` is the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be simple, once you have accessed the cast...

```
Route::get('movies', function()
{
    $movie = Movie::find(1);
    $cast  = $movie->cast;

    return View::make('movies')->with(array(
        'movie' => $movie,
         'cast' => $cast));
});
```

> **Note**: at this point, `$cast` is an instance of the `Collection` class, not a single object of the `MovieCast` class, as the
>   relationship is defined with `hasMany()`

you can iterate over it in the `View` (in my case `/app/views/movies.blade.php`

```
  @foreach($cast as $cast_member)
    <p>{{ $cast_member->person->name }}</p>
  @endforeach
```

---

**Class definitions used for testing:**

```
class Movie extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'movie_id';
    protected $table = 'movie';
    public $timestamps = false;

    // Relationships
    public function cast()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('MovieCast', 'movie_id');
    }
}

class MovieCast extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'movie_cast';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person', 'person_id');
    }

}

class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';
    protected $table = 'people';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function movieCast()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('MovieCast', 'person_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu, cara! This how I had tried to access the `name` property but got the error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$person`. Looks like there must be something wrong with how I defined the relationship between the `MovieCast` class and the `Person` class. Any ideas? By the way, what would be a better name for the `person()` method?

Comment: Imagine!  ok.. can you update your question with your current code, the code that's giving that error?  let me dig out the code I wrote to test this, and I'll update my answer as well.  Not sure about what to rename it to.. I just get confused when there are lots of similarly named classes :)

Comment: Made the edit above. The classes are identical to the ones you have used to test.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo that I have amended - the error I describe above still persists. If, however, I use `$cast  = $movie->cast` I get the error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$person`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm now getting `Trying to get property of non-object` error, `person` being the non-object in this case. Performing a `var_dump` of each `cast_member` shows no `person` object on `cast_member`. Sorry about this and thanks for the help.

Comment: strange.. are you sure that you're using the same code as above?  I'll update with my `Route`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42364/discussion-between-msturdy-and-garethdn)