# Only first() works for nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble accessing a nested relationship from a collection of models. If I use `first()` I can access the relationship of that specific model. For example...

```
public function movie($id)
{
    $member = Movie::find($id)->cast()->first()->person;

    return View::make('movie')->with(array(
        'data' => $member
    ));     
}
```

In this case `echo $data` forms a result like `{"person_id":"10255","name":"Paul Benedict"}`. That's fine but if I try doing something like...

```
$cast = Movie::find($id)->cast;

return View::make('movie')->with(array(
    'data' => $cast
));
```

If, in my view, I then try to print out each person like so...

```
foreach ($data->person as $member) {
    echo $member;
}
```

I get the following error:

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$person`

What exactly am I doing wrong and how do I do it correctly?

[Follow on from previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316845/accessing-nested-relationship-with-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time no speak! :)  I'm going to go through this step-by-step (as much for my own understanding)

First, in this case, we take the following steps:

```
$member = Movie::find($id)->cast()->first()->person;
```

1. `Movie::find($id)->cast()` - here we have a [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) of `MovieCast` objects.
2. `->first()` - we take the first `MovieCast` and...
3. ... `->person` - we take the `Person` object that's linked to the `MovieCast` object.

Now, we have an instance of the `Person` object in the $member variable.  Maybe he has a name, or some other attributes (`created_at`, `modified_at`, `age`, whatever).

**Let's look at the other case:**

```
$cast = Movie::find($id)->cast;
```

Here we only have a [`Collection`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) of `MovieCast` objects in the `$cast` variable.  When we loop over this Collection, we will get back instances of the MovieCast object.

So, we need to loop over these objects like this (in the `movie` view):

```
// I've used the same $data variable as you're defining in your Controller.
@foreach($data as $d)

    // each $d is a MovieCast object, so you can access his ->person() method.
    <pre>{{ $d->person->name }}</pre>

@endforeach
```

The problem is that by running `->person` in the foreach, you were running it against the Collection object, which doesn't have a person() method; hence the error!

Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense and I now understand where I was going wrong - specifically the final line `The problem is that by running ->person in the foreach, you were running it against the Collection object, which doesn't have a person() method`. Thanks again - it's now working how I intend